# UITapGestureRecognizer not responding on PDFView in ios13.1

Tags: swift, ios13

When adding UITapGestureRecognizer on PDFView selector method not called in iOS 13+ devices but running fine in below OS versions.

```
let barHideOnTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()
barHideOnTapGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(gestureRecognizedToggleVisibility(_:)))
        pdfview.addGestureRecognizer(barHideOnTapGestureRecognizer)

@objc func gestureRecognizedToggleVisibility(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if navigationController != nil {
            if !bottomView.isHidden {
                hideBars()
            } else {
                showBars()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Have the same issue. Apple added some own gestures to the PDFView. I could solve with the following:

```
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapped(_:)))
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    tapGesture.delegate = pdfView
    if let gestures = pdfView.gestureRecognizers{

        for gesture in gestures {

            if let gesture = gesture as? UITapGestureRecognizer, gesture.numberOfTapsRequired == 1{
            tapGesture.require(toFail: gesture)
            }
        }
    }

    pdfView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

Also for the PDFView i created a subclass of it and set the following UIGestureRecognizerDelegate method:

```
class DKPDFView : PDFView {

    override func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

have you added this line ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is fixed for iOS 13.2.2